# Regex to get everything between and including curly braces only if a given condition

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

Hello I am trying to create a regex which will grab everything **between** and **including** the curly braces **only** if the string between braces **starts** with **#** and if there is a **\n** after the **closing** curly brace **}**

I have this following string as an example -

```
## Markdown Syntax {#markdown-syntax}\n\n (lorem ipsum test).\n\n## Headers {#headers}\n\n function HelloCodeTitle(props) {return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>; } {2}
```

In this example, I am looking to extract `{#markdown-syntax}` and `{#headers}` from the above string and replace them with empty space `''`

I have written [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/h9s8DU/1) but this is also grabbing `{return <h1>Hello, {props.name}` and `{2}` which I do not want. I am only looking to grab  `{#markdown-syntax}` and `{#headers}` (including braces) as the string between braces **starts** with **#** and there is a **\n** after the **closing** curly brace **}**

Comment: `\n` is newline character or ``\`` followed by `n`?

Comment: It is actual "\n" in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `match()` with the appropriate pattern:

```js
var input = "## Markdown Syntax {#markdown-syntax}\n\n (lorem ipsum test).\n\n## Headers {#headers}\n\n function HelloCodeTitle(props) {return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>; } {2}";
var tags = input.match(/\{#.*?\}(?=\n)/g, input);
console.log(tags);
```

The regex pattern used above says to:

```regex
\{      match opening {
#       match #
.*?     match all content up the first
\}      closing }
(?=\n)  assert that what follows is a newline character
```

If you want to *remove* these tags, then use `replace` with the same pattern:

```js
var input = "## Markdown Syntax {#markdown-syntax}\n\n (lorem ipsum test).\n\n## Headers {#headers}\n\n function HelloCodeTitle(props) {return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>; } {2}";
var output = input.replace(/\s*\{#.*?\}(?=\n)/g, " ").trim();
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am looking to replace "{#markdown-syntax}",
  "{#headers}" with empty space from the string. Is it possible ?

Comment: Hey just a quick question. Is it possible to grab the last one only? For example if I want to just grab the ```{#headers}``` only. I.e the last one after you find the match?

Comment: Use this pattern: `\s*\{#.*?\}(?=\n)(?!.*\{#.*\}\n)` ... add a negative lookahead to ensure that it is the last match.

Comment: hey thanks but reaching out again as I have [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/bYiZQV/1) and I am looking to get the last occurrence of the given condition(. i.e I am looking to grab ```{#headers}``` 
In simple words, a regex which will grab last occurrence of everything between and including the curly braces only if the string between braces starts with # and if there is a \n after the closing curly brace }